# How to set offset to beginning in JDBC Source Connector to fetch all data from MySQL table in Kafka

Tags: mysql, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have added JDBC Source Connector using Kafka Connect which is fetching data from a MySQL table.

The connector is added successfully and data is flowing in it in real time.

But the corresponding topic does not contain all previous data.

I have tried restarting Kafka Connect.

Here is my JDBC Source Connector Configuration :

```
{
"name": "kb_yp_loan",
"connector.class": "io.aiven.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
"tasks.max": "1",
"key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
"value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
"value.converter.schema.registry.url": "XXXX",
"value.converter.basic.auth.credentials.source": "USER_INFO",
"value.converter.basic.auth.user.info": "XXXX",
"config.action.reload": "restart",
"connection.url": "jdbc:mysql://XXXX/XX?user=XXXX&password=XXXX&useCursorFetch=true&defaultFetchSize=1000",
"connection.user": "XXXX",
"connection.password": "XXXX",
"table.whitelist": "yp_loan",
"mode": "incrementing",
"incrementing.column.name": "id",
"topic.prefix": "kb_"
```

}

Please suggest how can I bring all previous data in my Kafka topic.

Comment: What do you mean, that there is _not contain all previous data_?

Comment: I mean that the data I got in topic is not the entire data which is present in MySQL table

Comment: How did you check that? How did you consume from topic? "Previous" based on what value?

Comment: Not sure what exactly question but u can use bulk to load all data from DB table to topic...ref : https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-jdbc/source-connector/index.html

Answer (score 1):

As you use the "**incrementing**" mode, the JDBC connector stores the last ID processed in a file, the offset file. To resend all data you just need to remove this offset file. There is another properties where you have to set this file path:

```
# Local storage file for offset data
offset.storage.file.filename=</path/file.offsets>
```

Restart the JDBC Source Connector and it will fetch and send all data FROM your table TO your topic.

Answer (score 0):

In the `connect-distributed.properties`, you need to add `consumer.auto.offset.reset=earliest` to start the Connect consumer instances to read all existing topic data.

Otherwise, the connector starts at the current,latest topic offsets.